# Write spark dataframe into existing parquet hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Want to write spark dataframe into existing parquet hive table. I am able to do it using`df.write.mode("append").insertI to("myexistinghivetable")`but if I check through file system I could see spark files are landed with .c000 extension.
What those files mean? And how to write dataframe into parquet hive table.

Comment: I don't know the hive table location that will be decided run time based on the partition values. Again can't we directly write dataframe into hive parquet table without workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it using `df.write.partitionBy("mypartitioncols").format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("hivetable")`
In earlier version of spark save mode append was not there.

Answer (score 2):

You can save dataframe as parquest at location where your hive table is referring after that you can alter tables in hive

You can do like this

```
df.write.mode("append").parquet("HDFS directory path")
```

Comment: In my case hive location will be decided run time. Why should we not write dataframe directly into hive table instead of doing workarounds. Currently I am able to write the data into hive table but my only concern is why files are not created with . parquet instead of .c000